# TLIndexPathTools - Dynamically load tree table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, hierarchical-data

I'm using the new [TLIndexPathTools library](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) to create dynamic iOS table views.  Specifically, using the TLIndexPathTreeItem class to build a hierarchical drop down table structure.

From the "Outline" example, it seems the entire hierarchy must be generated statically from the leaf nodes up to the parent nodes:

```
//setup item heirarchy for data model
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item111 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_1_1_1 level:2 children:nil];
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item112 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_1_1_2 level:2 children:nil];
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item11 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_1_1  level:1 children:@[item111, item112]];
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item121 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_1_2_1 level:2 children:nil];
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item12 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_1_2 level:1 children:@[item121]];
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item1 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_1 level:0 children:@[item11, item12]];
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item211 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_2_1_1 level:2 children:nil];
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item221 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_2_2_1 level:3 children:nil];
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item212 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_2_1_2 level:2 children:@[item221]];
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item21 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_2_1 level:1 children:@[item211, item212]];
TLIndexPathTreeItem *item2 = [self itemWithId:ITEM_2 level:0 children:@[item21]];
```

However, I have about 1,000 rows of data, which between 2-4 levels until each leaf.  Is there a way to populate each drop down dynamically as it's tapped?  Otherwise I need a huge recursive database call and some other hackery to load the entire tree structure into memory, then somehow set it up statically from leaf to parent as seen in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added support for lazy loading child nodes and updated the [Outline sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Outline/Outline/OutlineTableViewController.m) to demonstrate both synchronous and asynchronous loading.

The first thing to note is that nodes with `childItems == nil` are treated as leafs and thus the view controller will not attempt to expand or collapse them. So you need to set child items to an empty array if you want to lazy load a node.

The following `willChangeNode` delegate method has been added for synchronous loading:

```
- (TLIndexPathTreeItem *)controller:(TLTreeTableViewController *)controller willChangeNode:(TLIndexPathTreeItem *)treeItem collapsed:(BOOL)collapsed;
```

Just return a new item containing the children and it will replace the existing item. The easiest way to create the new item is to use the following convenience method:

```
TLIndexPathTreeItem *newTreeItem = [treeItem copyWithChildren:newChildren];
```

For asynchronous loading, initiate the fetch in the `didChangeNode` delegate method and call

```
[self setNewVersionOfItem:newTreeItem];
```

on the main thread in the fetch's completion handler (where `self` is the `TLTreeTableViewController`):

**EDIT** To elaborate on the asynchronous lazy loading, such as if you're getting the data from a server, it would look something like this:

```
- (void)controller:(TLTreeTableViewController *)controller didChangeNode:(TLIndexPathTreeItem *)treeItem collapsed:(BOOL)collapsed
{
    //the logic here checks that the node is being opened. Note that this will cause the
    //node to refresh every time it's expanded. If we only want to load children once,
    //we need to keep track of which nodes have been loaded (or maybe just check
    //that there are no child items yet: [treeItem.childItmes count] == 0).
    if (collapsed == NO) {

        //the next steps is to initiate a data fetch. So the hypothetical method
        //`fetchChildDataFromServerForItem` would execute the appropriate fetch for
        //the given item (to identify the item, one would typically look at the
        //`treeItem.identifier` property or maybe some information that has been placed
        //in `treeItem.data`.
        [self fetchChildDataFromServerForItem:treeItem completion:^(BOOL success, NSArray *result){

            //The fetch method would presumably have a completion block, where the result
            //data would be inserted into the tree.

            if (success && [result count] > 0) {

                //we build up an array of child items by looping over the result set. for arguments
                //sake, assume the result items are dictionaries (e.g. JSON data). They could just
                //as well be Core Data objects, strings, etc.
                NSMutableArray *childItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:result.count];
                for (NSDictionary *data in result) {
                    //TLIndexPathTools relies on items being identifiable, so we need to determine
                    //an appropriate identifier for our data. It could be the data object itself if it
                    //has a suitable `isEqual` method, such as with `NSString`. For a Core Data object,
                    //we would use the `objectID`. But for our dictionary items, we'll assume the
                    //dictionary contains a `recordId`.
                    NSString *identifier = [data valueForKey:@"recordId"];
                    //now we wrap our data in a tree item and add it to the array
                    TLIndexPathTreeItem *childItem = [[TLIndexPathTreeItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier sectionName:nil cellIdentifier:@"CellIdForThisLevel" data:data andChildItems:nil];
                    [childItems addObject:childItem];
                }
                //now we generate a new new node by copying the existing node, but providing a new set of children
                TLIndexPathTreeItem *newTreeItem = [treeItem copyWithChildren:childItems];
                //and finally ask the view controller to set our new tree item, which will cause the new
                //child items to appear in the table.
                [self setNewVersionOfItem:newTreeItem];

            } else {

                //perhaps if the fetch fails to return any items, we set the child items to nil
                //to indicate to the controller that this is a leaf node.
                TLIndexPathTreeItem *newTreeItem = [treeItem copyWithChildren:nil];
                [self setNewVersionOfItem:newTreeItem];

            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work with dynamic information?  If I have a data source on a server that updates, and I want to query it to load the tree.  Is there a way to never have to hard-code nodes and the hierarchy at every level?  Defining nodes in code with `TLIndexPathTreeItem *item1 = [self itemWithId:@"item header" level:2 children:nil];` for example is not going to scale.

Comment: Absolutely. Nodes are hard-coded in the example for the sake of simplicity. In your app, you'd get a data set from the server and build up your nodes by looping over the data and wrapping each data item in a new node. Make sense?

Comment: Edited my answer with a more detailed explanation of asynchronous lazy loading. This is about as detailed as I can get without knowing more specifics of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm going to spend some time trying to implement this.  Your library is great, and I love that it does simple and practical things for table views, and that it targets storyboards and ARC which many older libraries do not.  Would love to see examples in the future of how to fit everything together, like Outline with Dynamic Height, Sort, Shuffle, Core Data.

Comment: Thanks. Hope it works out. I'm slowly, but surely, adding more examples and documentation.

Comment: Wow! @TimothyMoose, it is one of the fastest feature requests I have seen! It took you about 12 hours since the question was asked until the solution was implemented, released and explained here in SO... Great work!